# backbone-stikit binding to disabled element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-stickit

i am using backbone and stikit for model binding, 
on some business cases the model sent from server may set a flag to disable a html element whose value is bound to another model attribute

The problem is that if a malicious user used the console to enable the element back and change its value, the model will be updated by stikit binding.

The question here what is the best practice to stop this behavior, keeping in mind that for business use the element data should rendered to show the data

Comment: Do you trust the client?

Comment: I do, the app will mainly run on intranet , but i don't want to depend just on trust ,

Comment: Never trust the client.

Comment: i just edit the comment :) don't want to depend on trust